# Oracle SQL Rewrite so field does not return invalid indentifier

Tags: sql, oracle

I am creating a view and you cannot create a view with a column outer-joined to a subquery, so I found another way to do it, but now I am having an issue with a field being out of scope.

```
create table registered (
crn number,
term varchar2(6));

create table course(
crn number,
term varchar2(6),
term_descrip varchar2(25));


insert into registered values (123,'202101');
insert into registered values (456,'202001');
insert into registered values (789,'202101');
insert into registered values (123,'202001');
insert into registered values (456,'201905');
insert into registered values (789,'202101');
insert into registered values (246,'202101');

insert into course values (123,'202001','Anatomy');
insert into course values (123,'202101','Physics');
insert into course values (456,'200001','English');
insert into course values (456,'201901','Algebra');
insert into course values (789,'199901','Gym');
```

Original Query

```
select r.crn,r.term, c.term_descrip from registered r
left join course c on c.crn =r.crn and c.term = 
(select max(c1.term) from course c1 where c.crn = c1.crn and
 c1.term <= r.term);
```

Results

| crn | term | descrip |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 123 | 202101 | Physics |
| 456 | 202001 | Algebra |
| 789 | 202101 | Gym |
| 123 | 202001 | Anatomy |
| 456 | 201905 | Algebra |
| 789 | 202101 | Gym |
| 246 | 202101 | null |

New query

```
select r.crn,r.term, max_term.term_descrip from registered r
 left join (select * from course c where 
            c.term = (select max(c1.term) from course c1 
                      where c.crn = c1.crn and c1.term <= r.term)) max_term
            on max_term.crn = r.crn
```

r.term gets invalid identifier since it is out of scope, how can I rewrite to get it into scope? Any suggestions are greatly appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have only one row for each combination of `crn` and `term` in `course` table, then you may consider lateral join:

> ```
> select r.crn, r.term, c.term_descrip
> from registered r 
>   outer apply(
>     select *
>     from course c
>     where c.crn = r.crn
>       and c.term <= r.term
>     order by c.term desc
>     fetch first 1 rows only
>   ) c
> ```
>
> ```
> CRN | TERM   | TERM_DESCRIP
> --: | :----- | :-----------
> 123 | 202101 | Physics     
> 456 | 202001 | Algebra     
> 789 | 202101 | Gym         
> 123 | 202001 | Anatomy     
> 456 | 201905 | Algebra     
> 789 | 202101 | Gym         
> 246 | 202101 | null
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=3043418108311c16beb37f9316330181)*

Answer (score 0):

Would this modification of your "original" query do?

```
SQL> select r.crn,r.term, c.term_descrip from registered r
  2  left join course c on c.crn =r.crn
  3  where c.term = (select max(c1.term)
  4                  from course c1
  5                 where c.crn = c1.crn
  6                   and c1.term <= r.term);

       CRN TERM   TERM_DESCRIP
---------- ------ -------------------------
       123 202101 Physics
       456 202001 Algebra
       789 202101 Gym
       123 202001 Anatomy
       456 201905 Algebra
       789 202101 Gym

6 rows selected.

SQL>
```

What's being changed? `AND` switched to `WHERE` :)